# no.de pull from github

Tags: node.js, ssh, github, putty, joyent

I am trying to pull or clone a git repo from my joyent smartmachine no.de thru putty. I can connect to my sever easily, but as soon as I write:

`git pull git@github.com/accoutName/repo` , I get the following error:

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up
>   unexpectedly

How do I find my smartmachine ssh key to copy and paste it in my github account settings?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use ssh to pull your repo, you need to add your machine's public rsa key to your github account. If you can create one on your smart machine, it should work. You shouldn't need to use ssh unless you want to read AND write though. I believe github provides read only urls to your repo witch might be a better solution.

When it comes down to it, the way you're supposed to deploy to your smart machine, is to push to the repo that's set up on it. As far as I know, you can't deploy by having it pull from another repo.

EDIT:
Some resources that will help out a lot would be http://help.github.com/ and http://wiki.joyent.com/display/node/Node.js+Home

Comment: Github only hosts your git repository. In order to push it to your Smart Machine, you have to clone the repository on your own local machine. From there you can add your Smart Machine as a `remote` and push to it. There is a lot of help out there that can walk you through the process.

Answer (score 0):

Workflow is like this:

```
git clone $REPO $DIR
cd $DIR
git remote add joyent $NODEURL
git push joyent
```

Not like this:

```
ssh $NODEURL
git clone $REPO
```

Comment: How can I push from my joyent smartmachine, you mean push from the git machine, but how can I connect ot github and initiate a push?

Comment: @guiomie: No no no. You push from *your* machine to the SmartMachine.

Comment: @Hello71 - you've completely misread the question. He knows how to do that, he wants to pull from the node.js smart machine. There are several use cases why this would be necessary. E.g. a smart application which manages different dependencies by cloning them out itself.

Comment: Ok, I added a config file and use git bash on my desktop. But now I keep getting this error:

ssh: connect to host mysite.no.de port 54567: Bad file number

Comment: The bad file number was because I had put the wrong port number in my config file. Problem solved :P

Answer (score 0):

look in ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub or ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub and upload those to github.